# mutli-step regex matching into one expression

Tags: regex, xpath, xquery

(In XQuery 3.1) I am trying to identify strings which match the following conditions.

The user may include in the string the encoded HTML `&lt;br/&gt;` but otherwise may not include `<`, `>` nor `&lt;` or `&gt;` separately. I can do this in a two-step test, by first stripping out `&lt;br/&gt;`:

```
 let $newstring := replace($string,"&lt;br/&gt;","")
 let $testresult := matches($newstring,"(&lt;)|(&gt;)|<|>")
```

Where `$testresult` returns `true` or `false` based on these `string`s

- `and this is a sentence with a permitted &lt;br/&gt; break` = false
- `and this is a sentence with a permitted &lt;br/&gt; and a disallowed <br/> string` = true
- `and this is a sentence with a disallowed <br/> string` = true
- `and this is a sentence with a disallowed < character` = true
- `and this is a sentence with a disallowed &gt; string` = true

But I wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution possible within a single regular expression.

Nb nesting does not appear to work `let $testresult := matches(replace($string,"&lt;br/&gt;",""),"(&lt;)|(&gt;)|<|>")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wst pointed out negative lookbehinds cannot be used in XPath functions. Therefore I came up with this workaround for my initial answer using character classes.

`(&lt;(?!br\/&gt;))| [^&]?[^l]?[^t]?[^;]?[^b]?[^r]?[^\/]?&gt;|<|>`

In case you can use negative lookbehinds this might work for you. [Demo](https://regexr.com/4jkdt)

`(&lt;(?!br\/&gt;))|((?<!&lt;br\/)&gt;)|<|>`

It gives a match for the last four examples you provided but does not match for the first one.

Comment: Lookarounds are not supported in XPath functions, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @wst. I updated my answer with a workaround that does not need a negative lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks - however this part `[^&]?[^l]?[^t]?[^;]?[^b]?[^r]?[^\/]?&gt;|<|>` produces an XPATH error that I can't get to the bottom of: `exerr:ERROR expecting '"', found '&'`

Comment: @wst, some XQuery/XPath processors like Saxon or BaseX allow you to use the platform's (e.g. Java or .NET) regular expression support with a flag (e.g. `;j` (as part of the `flags` arguments of the various regular expression functions) for Saxon or BaseX and the Java platform) and that way, if the the platform supports it, lookaheads or lookbehinds can be used.

Comment: @jbrehr, keep in mind that the answer is not in the context of XQuery but simply strings and regular expressions in general, so if you use it inside of XQuery you have to make sure your string literals are following XQuery syntax rules and therefore the `&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;` in the string to be parseable by the XQuery parser.